# Why does Core Data Name the tables and attributes it creates in SQLite with a Z prefix?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite, core-data

Just curious to know why all the tables and Entities show up with a Z prefix in front of their names when i browse them with a SQLite database browser. The entity in my DB is named Assignment in code, and when i browse it, its named ZASSIGNMENT.

Comment: Because U were to important! *jk*

Answer (score 2):

It may be a naming convention by Team Apple for Core Data SQLite.

Reason may be :

1. Z is one of the least used letters of the alphabet. So less chances of name collision.
2. Using Z in capital makes it stand out as it will be shown as last in the list.

Even SAP uses Z as prefix in their table names.